# How to bind Radcombobox items client side with database values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, rad-controls, radcombobox

I am using oracle as my back end. how to bind radcombobox with database(oracle) table values form client side.
as follows if i have emp table then columns are emp id and name so i has to bind emp id and name to rad combo box form client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get your values using ajax method (you can use ajax method of jquery).

```
function BindListToCombo(cbo, list) {
   $find(cbo).clearItems();
   $.each(list, function (a, item) {
      var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
      comboItem.set_text(item.Name);
      comboItem.set_value(item.Id);
      $find(cbo).get_items().add(comboItem);
});
var comboItem = $find(cbo).findItemByValue(0);
comboItem.select();}
```

Use this function to bind the list to combo.

Comment: thanks for reply, what is code for code behind in cs file will you plz share it.

Comment: Write a web-method with return type of JSON List. Call that method using jquey-Ajax method

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/287430/Calling-ASP-Net-WebMethods-using-jQuery